# AngularJS - Compare date using filterFilter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

In controller using `filterFilter` to filter data in json object like below

`self.InfoAlerts = filterFilter(self.alerts, {Type:'Info'});`

Which returns json object only if `Type` is `Info`. Is it possible to compare date and return object if the date value from json object is less than 2 weeks?

Refered: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Answer (score 1):

No,you need to use a custom filter for this.

The default filter in angular is just a simple text filter and is very similar to the Arra.filter() of javascript.

```
Array.filter()
```

You can refer to the same docs for writing that custom filter requirement.
Also, in your use case I don't see a need to use apply the filter in controller and you can use it in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and already used the custom filter at many places in our project.  I just wanted if it is possible using ``filterFilter``.